Angular 17 SSR Dynamic Routing Not Working On Page Reload
Recently I've upgraded Angular project into 17 with SSR. We have perameterize dynamic routing in router.ts file like below.
export const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'buy-car/find-a-car',
  loadComponent: () => import('./buy-car/new-buy-car-list/new-buy-car-list.component').then(m => m.NewBuyCarListComponent)                
},
{
 path: 'buy-car/find-a-car/:single',
 loadComponent: () => import('./buy-car/new-buy-car-list/new-buy-car-list.component').then(m => m.NewBuyCarListComponent)             
},
{
 path: 'buy-car/find-a-car/:province/:bodytype',
 loadComponent: () => import('./buy-car/new-buy-car-list/new-buy-car-list.component').then(m => m.NewBuyCarListComponent)               
}
]

angular.json was like this
{
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "prerender": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

After that I did research and found this https://angular.dev/guide/prerendering . Based on this I had updated
"prerender": { 
   "discoverRoutes": false 
} 

and all dynamic routing is working But site speed goes down to 5-6 second. Before it site was load in miliseconds.
So, applied another solution that Is routesFile. In router.txt file I've added 10-12 dynamic router for testing and it's working well. Even site is loading In miliseconds like before.
"prerender": {
   "routesFile": "routes.txt"
}

router.txt file
/learn/maintaining-your-car/maintaining-my-car-with-a-service-plan
/learn/maintaining-your-car/maintaining-your-car-with-a-maintenance-plan

Now Issue Is on the website we have 1000+ blogs and manage it from CMS (Devloped In Node). So, we can't do like everytime add new blog routes in router.txt file.
And except this blogs we have many more dynamic routes in router.ts file.
One more weired thing Is all routes are working locally with SSR and without SSR. Only it's not working on server (Azure).
So, guys please suggest if you have any solution or idea.
All parameterized dynamic router work on page reload.

I am having similar problem, could you resolve this issue?

@HeyBaldur Yes I've resolved. https://angular.dev/guide/prerendering
You have to pre load all dynamic routes in routes.txt files.

Ok so i think I found a solution to render this dynamic route page
 constructor(
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private blogPublicService: BlogPublicService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private transferState: TransferState,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string
  ) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.initializeData();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Subscribe to route parameters to detect changes
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getBlogPost(params['slug']);
    });
  }

  async initializeData(): Promise<void> {
    const params = await firstValueFrom(this.activatedRoute.params);
    this.getBlogPost(params['slug']);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/require-await
  async getBlogPost(slug: string): Promise<void> {
    if (this.transferState.hasKey(BLOG_POST_KEY)) {
      this.blogPost = this.transferState.get(BLOG_POST_KEY, null);
      this.loading = false;
    } else {
      this.loading = true;
      this.blogPublicService.getBySlug(slug).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IBlogPost>) => {
        this.blogPost = res.body!;
        this.loading = false;
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
          this.transferState.set(BLOG_POST_KEY, this.blogPost);
        }
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });
    }
  }

With this, the initial HTML page contains the blogpost, without having pre-render routes. Im not sure how you should update the sitemap to sync it with the blogposts, but so far this renders the html ok.
